# Wordpress Search Function to only search posts

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I want to use the wordpress search function but I want it to only search my blog posts and exclude my static pages from the query. How to do this? I am not opposed to using a plugin.

Comment: Your fix will get over-written when you update WordPress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wp forum page has a bunch of different examples of how to do this depending on where you want to edit your site (index.php or wp-includes/query.php are your options I believe):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-search-only-posts-exclude-pages

Comment: Hm, seems this is one of the best posts out there - but to be honest it isn't a great deal of help. The two primary methods are A) Hacking the core (which you shouldn't do) B) Discarding the unwanted results in the template (inefficient)

Must be an easier way to control what the search is searching - surprising WP don't have a function for it.

Comment: if you look at the dates you can see the post is over 3.5 years old. I'd hope there's something better out there by now that relates to the latest version of WP.

Answer (score 47):

Answer is here

http://www.shilling.id.au/2011/06/23/wordpress-search-only-show-post-and-not-pages/

```
<?php
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
?>
```

Comment: The accepted answer (and the linked forum post) outline poor results. It's never a good idea to edit core files, and skipping results in the foreach loop could result in messy things when pagination is involved. This hook is a much better solution!

Comment: This is actually **not** a good answer, unless you want to only search for posts in EVERY search field on your site.  So any search fields in the admin area and anywhere else will probably break, unless you want to use them all for searching posts only.  
This may not be obvious immediately after implementation of this solution, but down the track you can bet it will cause problems.

Comment: Is there a way to get this functionality to work in a search bar that only appears on blog pages? It seems like this is for WP admin, but I'm trying to make something on the user-side so they can search blog posts from any /blog/ page.

Answer (score 45):

Simply add  `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />` to the theme search form... regards!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible (or easy) to implement in all cases. For example, my search form is made by Elementor and I can't edit it.

Answer (score 6):

This solution makes the search retrieve only posts if you haven't specified a different post type. This method wont interfere if you specify a custom post type in a hidden field in a different search field.

```
function searchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        if ( !isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) ) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchFilter');
```

Answer (score 3):

The outlined solutions are poor. Editing the core impedes on upgradeability of the WordPress install - you'll have to repeat that change every time you update, which you should be doing. The other solution places unnecessary load on the database by filtering results *after* retrieving them. The better solution:

In your theme's functions.php, add a new function to write out a search form:

```
function custom_search_form( $form, $value = "Search", $post_type = 'post' ) {
    $form_value = (isset($value)) ? $value : attribute_escape(apply_filters('the_search_query', get_search_query()));
    $form = '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="' . get_option('home') . '/" >
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="'.$post_type.'" />
        <input type="text" value="' . $form_value . '" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'.attribute_escape(__('Search')).'" />
    </div>
    </form>';
    return $form;
}
```

Now, in the template where you want the form (or within any widgets you've created, this could easily be registered as a widget instead), this:

```
<?= custom_search_form( null, 'Search posts', 'post'); ?>
```

The arguments could be left out from the function & call, but I find them helpful. The key to this whole thing is the hidden input 'post_type', which passes the value to the query. The default, `post`, will ensure only posts are returned.

Comment: Actually, this does not work.  It returns all pages as well as posts in the search.

Comment: Actually, this does work.  This is the best solution IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<?php if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='page')) continue; ?>
```

Try this one and tell me if works.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the query with global query.

```
   global $wp_query;    
   $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );  
   query_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP Search http://wpsear.ch/ and you can configure which post types to show in results.

Comment: That link is now broken. Please delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</label>
                    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) .'" />
                </div>'
            </form>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If using multiple search forms, the following code is useful to limit a specific form to `post_type` post.

```
/**
 * Modify search query
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query
 *
 * @return void
 */
function theme_modify_search( $query ) {
 
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
        
    if( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if( isset( $_GET, $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', $_GET['post_type'] );
        }
    }
 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'theme_modify_search' );
```

For more details: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-a-specific-search-form-to-post-only/